# SQL: How do I GROUP BY two columns as unordered pairs?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, sqlalchemy

I am implementing a chat system with MySQL using SQLAlchemy as my ORM.
 
My table has the following columns: `id, from_user_id, to_user_id, message, time_sent.`

I'm trying to create a query in which I select the record containing the latest message sent from each conversation. This is exactly like the list of conversations that one would see on Facebook. 
Any ideas on how to do this?
Here is what I have so far:

```
latest_msg_sq = (DBSession.query(func.max(Message.id).label("max_id"))
.group_by(Message.from_user)).subquery()    
matching_conv = DBSession.query(Message)
.join(latest_msg_sq, and_(Message.id ==  
latest_msg_sq.c.max_id)).order_by(Message.time_sent.desc())
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work so well because it only gets the latest message of from_user_id. I need it to also consider messages from to_user_id, and group_by doesn't seem to be the best way to do this. In my opinion, I think I need to consider records from_user_id and to_user_id as unordered pairs and then use group_by on these pairs. However, I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Chat apps usually have a *room* abstraction, which are implemented with their own unique id. Instead of trying to turn a `from_user_id` plus a `to_user_id` into a conversation, perhaps it would be better if your `messages` table had the following columns: `id, owner, room, message, time_sent`, so you can select by `room` and order by `time_sent`.

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL, you would use `least()` and `greatest()`.  To get the most recent time:

```
select least(from_user_id, to_user_id) as u1, greatest(from_user_id, to_user_id) as u2,
       max(time_sent) as maxts
from messages
group by least(from_user_id, to_user_id), greatest(from_user_id, to_user_id)
```

To get the full messages, you would join this back in:

```
select m.*
from (select least(from_user_id, to_user_id) as u1, greatest(from_user_id, to_user_id) as u2,
             max(time_sent) as maxts
      from messages
      group by least(from_user_id, to_user_id), greatest(from_user_id, to_user_id)
     ) m2 join
     messages m
     on least(m2.from_user_id, m2.to_user_id) = least(m.from_user_id, m.to_user_id) and
        greatest(m2.from_user_id, m2.to_user_id) = greatest(m.from_user_id, m.to_user_id)
```

I'm not sure how you would express this in SQLalchemy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select msg1.* from message msg1
left outer join message msg2 on 
(msg1.from_user_id = msg2.from_user_id 
and msg1.to_user_id = msg2.to_user_id and msg2.time_sent > msg1.time_sent)
left outer join message msg3 on 
msg1.to_user_id = msg3.from_user_id 
and msg1.from_user_id= msg3.to_user_id and msg3.time_sent > msg1.time_sent
where msg2.id is null and msg3.id is null
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to do this in SQLAlchemy?

Comment: They are simple left joins. I am not familiar with SQLAlchemy but any ORM supports left joins

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy version of Mohsen Heydari's answer for anyone who needs it:

```
msg1 = aliased(Message)
msg2 = aliased(Message)
msg3 = aliased(Message)
matching_conv = DBSession.query(msg1)
matching_conv = matching_conv.outerjoin(msg2, and_(msg1.from_user==msg2.from_user, msg1.to_user==msg2.to_user, msg2.id > msg1.id))
matching_conv = matching_conv.outerjoin(msg3, and_(msg1.to_user==msg3.from_user, msg1.from_user==msg3.to_user, msg3.id > msg1.id))
matching_conv = matching_conv.filter(and_(msg2.id == None, msg3.id == None)).order_by(msg1.time_sent.desc())
```